# Upload symbol show errors crashlytics

Tags: debug-symbols, crashlytics-android

I see such errors while uploading symbol files

> Blockquote
>   com.crashlytics.tools.utils.dwarf.DwarfException: Unable to set appropriate offset for compilation unit.
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.dwarf.DebugLineStateMachine.seekToOffsetForIndex(DebugLineStateMachine.java:59)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.dwarf.DebugLineStateMachine.runForIndex(DebugLineStateMachine.java:52)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.readDebugLineData(ElfDataParser.java:249)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.readDebugInfoSection(ElfDataParser.java:503)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.readDebugInfoSection(ElfDataParser.java:473)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.parseElf(ElfDataParser.java:148)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.parse(ElfDataParser.java:122)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.parse(ElfDataParser.java:54)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.codemapping.csym.ElfCSymFactory.createCSymFromFile(ElfCSymFactory.java:97)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.codemapping.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateCodeMappings(NdkCSymGenerator.java:70)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.CSymManager.generate(CSymManager.java:96)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:692)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgsInternal(DeveloperTools.java:348)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.gradleMain(DeveloperTools.java:292)
>
> Blockquote
>   ERROR - Could not parse debug data.
>   com.crashlytics.tools.utils.dwarf.DwarfException: Unknown opcode: 176
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.dwarf.DebugLineStateMachine.getOpcode(DebugLineStateMachine.java:189)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.dwarf.DebugLineStateMachine.processOpcode(DebugLineStateMachine.java:161)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.dwarf.DebugLineStateMachine.readCompilationUnit(DebugLineStateMachine.java:123)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.dwarf.DebugLineStateMachine.run(DebugLineStateMachine.java:67)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.dwarf.DebugLineStateMachine.runForIndex(DebugLineStateMachine.java:53)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.readDebugLineData(ElfDataParser.java:249)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.readDebugInfoSection(ElfDataParser.java:503)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.readDebugInfoSection(ElfDataParser.java:473)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.parseElf(ElfDataParser.java:148)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.parse(ElfDataParser.java:122)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.ElfDataParser.parse(ElfDataParser.java:54)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.codemapping.csym.ElfCSymFactory.createCSymFromFile(ElfCSymFactory.java:97)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.codemapping.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateCodeMappings(NdkCSymGenerator.java:70)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.CSymManager.generate(CSymManager.java:96)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:692)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgsInternal(DeveloperTools.java:348)
>           at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.gradleMain(DeveloperTools.java:292)

Answer (score 0):

its frabric plugin issue. Try updating plugin to latest.